# Woocommerce Bundled product filters

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am Using WooCommerce Bundled Product plugin and I'm trying to get one of my Bundled product checked by default.

So far I have managed to find a way to get them all checked. Basically I'd like this filter to check if product type is subscription and then add the following filter.

Could someone help me with this one?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bundled_item_is_optional_checked', 'wc_pb_is_optional_item_checked', 10, 2 );
function wc_pb_is_optional_item_checked( $checked, $bundled_item ) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this (I am not sure at 100% as I don't use Bundled Products plugin):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bundled_item_is_optional_checked', 'wc_pb_is_optional_item_checked', 10, 2 );
function wc_pb_is_optional_item_checked( $checked, $bundled_item ) {
    // If an item of the bundled product is a subscription
    if(wc_get_product($bundled_item->item_id)->is_type('subscription')) 
         $checked = true;

    return $checked;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: No this did not work. I already tried a similiar solution but it brakes the bundle product selection. Thanks anyway :)